# c# - Reading NuGet feeds

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I would like to go through a series of nuGet packages from a feed, listing all the dll's that are in them.  I'm having a hard time getting useful info through google.  Any help in getting started?  If there is an open source tool that already does this let me know, better to not re-make the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest having a look at 
[NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/) which is a package viewer/editor that supports opening packages from a feed.

Alternatively, you can leverage nuget.exe to install a list of packages (installing in this case is just an unzip) then list the dlls from the folders.

example batch file :

```
@echo off
setlocal
nuget.exe list hashfoo -source https://nuget.org/api/v2/ > temp.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%G IN (temp.txt) DO (nuget.exe install %%G -version %%H)
DIR *.dll /S
endlocal
```

(it lists all packages with search term 'hashfoo' from the source, installs them and list all the dlls)

Comment: well, that is actually the power I want to leverage, just I want to be able to see -all- the dll's, instead of having to look at the list one package at a time.

Comment: added an example above, may not be the most elegant but it's shows it's possible with current tools.

Comment: Is there a way to list the dll's, without installing them?

Comment: I think you'll have to at least download them since nuget gallery doesn't track that data in the feed.
nupkg files are simply zip files, you could probably search inside them.
note: in the example, I'm not really installing them into any project, those files can just be deleted afterwards.